# Simple 24V to 5V converter circuit (Almost complete)

Tags: voltage-regulator

A couple of years ago I made a 24v to 5v circuit and it worked well. So I followed the same schematic.

[image]

My question is that I have no idea why I used those capacitors. Does it really matter what capacitors I use?

My circuit will only use like 50mA.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you to use? How about supplying a link to the data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka, does the data sheet tell you capacitor values for different loads and input voltage ranges?

Comment: It's an LM7805.

Comment: They use this https://gyazo.com/37ae99a82cee2078e248f958f7c8c31e

Comment: Does it really matter what capacitor I use? Because my circuit still works after so many years.

Comment: @TonyM if you are interested then take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Taken straight from the datasheet:

8.2.1.2.1 Input Capacitor
An input capacitor is required if the regulator is placed more than 3 inches from the power supply filter. A 0.33-µF
capacitor on the input is suitable for most applications.
8.2.1.2.2 Output Capacitor
TI recommends a minimum load capacitance of 0.01 µF to limit high-frequency noise.

Really for something like this, I don't think it will make a massive amount of difference, however, maybe 100uF is a bit excessive. It'll still work, but it does seem a tad large! Maybe you used those capacitors because they are the ones you happened to have to hand at the time? For a circuit using only 50mA, if it is working and continues to work, then I don't think it would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Which datasheet did you find? Mine didnt have that.

Comment: I used the one here:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/lm78l05-406827.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Btw do you think (24-5)V*0.05A=0.95W of dissipation is ok?

Comment: Depends what package you are using. The thermal information is also given on the datasheet. It's at the bottom of page 4

Comment: With 0.95W it may be an idea to consider a standard 7805 rather than a 78L05. They are pretty cheap these days and the 7805 can handle a bit more than the 78L05 can, and they do the same job!