# Design 30 to 5 V (up to 1.2 A) converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I need some help to make sure my design is correct.

I want to designing a pcb board for the pi-zero-W so it will connect to my system that works on 24-30 V.

The pi-zero-W use around 350 mA according to the datasheets, but they recommend power supply of 1.2 A in order to work without problems.
[raspberrypi- power](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply)

So I found this circuit here:
[Simple 24V to 5V converter circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302935/simple-24v-to-5v-converter-circuit-almost-complete)

I have some questions:

1. What is D3 needed for? Just to prevent "noise" in the input voltage?
2. What is D4 needed for? In case of malfunction on the 7805, it will prevent the input voltage to go to the output? And "save" the 5 V device (pi-zero-W)?
3. Does the C1, C2 will do the work for my needs? Or I need bigger C?

In my case the distance is more than 3 inches.

Or it will be best to use this device?
[P7805-2000-S](https://www.mouser.co.il/ProductDetail/CUI-Inc/P7805-2000-S?qs=GBLSl2AkirtGU70jx9b4PA%3D%3D)
And build a sutiable circuit around him also?
This is what they recommend in the datasheet:
[image: recommand circuit]

Or can you suggest another device?

Comment: (1) reverse polarity protection. (2) prevents output voltage exceeding input voltage, read datasheet (3) Depends on the circuit you're designing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what does D3 needed for ?*

[image]

D3 prevents reverse voltages misapplied to the input destroying the regulator chip.

But this circuit won't be good enough for supplying anything more than a few tens of mA. You need to use a buck converter and not a linear regulator because linear regulators will get very hot in this application when supplying hundreds of mA (and you need amps!).

So basically I'm not going to labour over the other questions other than to say that the  P7805-2000-S is a more suitable choice but, it can only supply 2 amps: -

[image]

Comment: 2 amps it's more then I need , I post that the PI wiki say PI-Zero-w need power supply of 1.2A . so no problem there..   I have added in the post the recommand circuit , do I need to add the Diodes like in the LM7805 ? Thanks ,

Comment: I'd add the diodes and bear in mind that it's a 78L05 not an LM7805. You said 2.5 amps in your title.

Comment: sorry - fix this . so you say it will be good idea to add D3,D4 also for the P78-2000-S ?

Comment: If there's a chance that the input supply can be wrongly applied then add D3. D4 is needed in some specific cases to prevent damage to 78x0y devices from being destroyed should power be applied to the output.

Comment: what do you mean by this? that the  plus and minus will be reverse? don't think it posiable .  and it's seems that I will be use the  P78-2000-S and not the lm7805 , it's seems much better for what I need , no ?

Comment: If you don't think it's possible then you don't need to fit the diodes.

Comment: OK , thank you very much for the help